# validate() is not a function in ember-cp-validation

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, ember-cp-validations

I am using ember-cp-validation in ember js application for validation. using validate() method in components page. but i am getting error(validate is not a function). I referred this [link](https://embermap.com/video/ember-cp-validations)

In models page(profile.js),

```
import DS from 'ember-data';
import { validator, buildValidations } from 'ember-cp-validations';

const Validations = buildValidations({
    name: validator('presence', true),

    address:[
        validator('presence', true),
        validator('length', { max: 300}),
    ],

    pincode: validator('presence', true),

    email:[
        validator('presence', true),
        validator('format', {type:'email'})
    ]

});

export default DS.Model.extend(Validations,{
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    address: DS.attr('string'),
    pincode: DS.attr('number'),
    email: DS.attr('string')
});
```

And Components page,

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({     
    actions: {
        authenticate() {            
            let profile = this.get('profile');
            profile.validate().then(({ validations }) => {
                if(validations.get('isValid')){
                    this.transitionToRoute("welcome");
                }
            });         
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: are you sure `profile` attribute of the component is indeed an instance of the `model` for which you have defined validations?

Comment: 'profile' is models filename.

Answer (score 0):

In my component I'm using:

- `this.get('model').validate()` to force a validation,
- `this.get('isValid')` to know if the current input is valid.

So you could do:

```
this.get('model').validate().then(() => {
  if (this.get('isValid')) {
    this.transitionToRoute("welcome");
  }
});
```